# How to use `laravel-backup`-Package with Laravel Vapor

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, database-backups, laravel-vapor

We are using [Laravel Vapor](https://vapor.laravel.com/) to manage our laravel application and planing to use the [laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) package to create automated database backups for our **production environment**.

I testet the implementation and managed to get it worked (with version `7.3.3`) on my windows machine.

I set the mail configuration to get notified when an backup runs (successful or not) and set the path to `mysqldump` like this:

```
'dump' => [
    'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin',
    'use_single_transaction',
    'timeout' => 60 * 5,
]
```

To set this up and running with vapor, I changed the `destination.disk`-config from `local` to `s3` with `s3` as

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
],
```

I removed the `dump_binary_path`, because I didn't know where to point with it in the context of vapor. So I hoped that it is at a default location as it is mentioned in the [docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/installation-and-setup#dumping-the-database) of the `laravel-backup` package:

> mysqldump is used to backup MySQL databases. pg_dump is used to dump PostgreSQL databases. If these binaries are not installed in a default location, you can add a key named dump.dump_binary_path in Laravel's own database.php config file.

I included the `backup` command in the `kernel`-file

```
$schedule->command('backup:clean')->daily()->at('01:00');
$schedule->command('backup:run --only-db')->daily()->at('01:30');
```

and deployed it with vapor.

Unfortunately it isn't working. I didn't recived an email (neither success nor failure) and nothing was created at our `s3`.

**Does someone used `laravel-backup` with vapor before and knows how to fix this? What am I missing?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but do you already know that [Laravel Vapor automatically backs up your db, and you can restore it to any point in time](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/databases.html#restoring-databases)?

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel Vapor support replied this:
"Our native runtime doesn't have mysqldump installed. You will need to run the Docker runtime and install yourself if this is a requirement. It's also worth noting the maximum execution time on Lambda is 15 mins so if your backup is large, you could run into issues."